# Using an input scanner in an if statement

Tags: java

im making a program that uses an array to store a guestlist. One of the options in the menu is to add a guest, but when i try this option it doesnt wait for user to make its name input and immedietly jumps to the next statement wich asks for the age. Please help!

```
    else if(choice==3){
      System.out.print("Name of guest: ");
      String name = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Age of guest: ");
      String age = input.nextLine();
      addGuest(name,age);
      }
```

output: Name of guest: Age of guest:

Update: I managed to solve the problem by adding input.nextLine(); after the first print. I dont really understand the explanation given here [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) but it worked.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code please? have you created a new Scanner object?

Comment: How have you initialized the Scanner?  Should be input = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Right after all of the the nextFoo() line, please put a print statement showing what was input. This should answer your question